# Redirect Main Domain to folder By htaccess file Cpanel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, cpanel

I am trying to redirect the main domain to the folder public directory by .htaccss. I wrote the below code on .htaccess file. but the index.php file is downloaded when I hit the domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?xxx.com$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foldername/public/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foldername/$1
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?xxx.com$
 RewriteRule ^(/)?$ foldername/public/index.php [L]
```

Comment: If the file is _downloaded_ then two things can be said: 1. the rewriting works, since the http server can access the file and 2. it appears that php is not configured correctly inside your http server.

Comment: Presumably the file is "downloaded" when you request the file directly, regardless of the directives in `.htaccess`?

Comment: I changed the last line and removed the index.php but still, the index file is downloaded.